# Adding map to a seaborn scatterplot

Tags: python, dictionary, seaborn

Starting from this data

```
    USER_LONG | USER_LAT | NUMBER_OF_USER_AT_LOCATION   
0   24.909  60.154  2   
1   24.909  60.155  3   
2   24.909  60.156  3   
3   24.909  60.157  3   
4   24.909  60.158  1
```

I have made a scatter plot using seaborn by giving the coordinates as x and y parameter. The scope of the scatter was to show how many users are in the same location.

```
sns.scatterplot(x=geo_data.USER_LONG, y=geo_data.USER_LAT, hue=geo_data.NUMBER_OF_USER_AT_LOCATION, 
size=geo_data.NUMBER_OF_USER_AT_LOCATION, sizes=(20, 200), palette="magma", legend="full")
```

Which result in the following plot
[image]

I would like to underlay this scatter plot the map of the city (Helsinki) to make the plot more understandable. I have tried using geopandas but without any results this because it seems that the coordinate of the map that I found here: https://hri.fi/data/en_GB/dataset/helsingin-liikennevaylat/resource/a678f192-871d-486d-b45b-32a3a343f85a don't correctly "communicate" with my data-set coordinate.

Here below my try

```
gdf = gpd.read_file("Hki_liikennevaylat.shp")
crs = {'init':'epsg:3857'}
geometry = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(geo_data["USER_LONG"], geo_data["USER_LAT"])]
geo_df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geo_data, crs = crs, geometry=geometry)
fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,15))
gdf.plot(ax=ax, alpha=0.4, color="grey")
geo_df.plot(ax=ax)
```

This results in two different plots and also I lost the information about the number of users in the same area.

Do you if there is a simple way to achieve what I would like?

Comment: what is your geopandas code? Can you include that in your question?

Comment: Added the geopandas code that I have used. Thanks

Comment: There seems to be a mismatch between coordinate systems. The website of the map you used says it uses EPSG:3879, so you could update the epsg number in your crs value with that.

Comment: Thanks, RJ Adriaansen, by fixing the coordinate system the plot now are on the same figure but it seems that there is still something wrong since they are not overlaid. But I have one in the bottom left and the other in the upper right. I have tried to fix the xlim and ylim but is not working.